# Stopping pdf-tools from resetting to the beginning of an open PDF when I eval-buffer my config file

Tags: init-file, pdf, eval-expression

I'm using `pdf-tools` to read PDFs in Emacs, and am pretty happy so far. However, I've found when I modify, and then `eval-buffer` my configuration file, the PDFs I opened earlier with `pdf-tools` get put back to their first page! This is highly annoying behaviour, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

For reference, all the config file contains that relates to pdf-tools is the necessary `(pdf-tools-install)` to ensure that it becomes operational.

Comment: Do you mean that evaluating the emacs `init.el` resets the pdf page to 1?

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yes, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/commit/5b153d7e445804041bba74bcfb6f35c7a27552c0